# Memory Loss for Java 8u6 on ARM (BeagleBoneBllack)

Tags: java, memory-leaks, arm

I am dealing with a memory effect for a Java program runnuing under Java 8u6 on ARM (a Beagle Bone Black).
When I start my program and in parallel run the "top" command, I can watch my application to constantly grow in RAM consumption. VIRT, RES and %MEM constantly grow.
This looks like a memory leak in my app.
So I started a jstatd, enabled JMX for my app and remotely connected to my app via VisualVM.
Looking into my app, Visual VM tells me about a heap usage of not more than 42MB. I set -Xms=128m for my app and this limit is by far never reached.
Looking at the metaspace it is constantly at 11MB. Taking memory samples tells me that there are no instances constantly growing.
Nothing indicates there could be a leak.
So I wonder where the memory goes. Any ideas on that ?

Comment: You mean `Xmx`, not `Xms`? Also, what do you mean by "heap usage"? What's the reported heap *size*?

Comment: I meant Xms. I think setting Xms implicitly sets Xmx to the same value if not defined otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

My fault...
I use JNI to access some hardware on the BBB. In Java I call the JNI providing a byte[].
In C I converted the byte[] to char[] using GetByteArrayElements but I forgot to release the array again with ReleaseByteArrayElements.
Thats where the memory went. After adding the Release... everything is fine now.